# PHP7.1 curl does not work

Tags: php, curl, php-7.1

I have tried to install php7.1-curl but I get only this response:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>        php7.1-curl : Depends: php7.1-common (= 7.1.8-1) but 7.1.1-1 is to be installed
>                    Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.44.0) but 7.38.0-4+deb8u5 is to be installed
>       E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: As it seems you have to install the two packages before

Comment: This is not the right forum to be asking these questions

Comment: This appears to be some Linux package system (Debian? Ubuntu?). You should probably provide that information in the question. Also, are you using third-party repositories?

Comment: `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` and try again. If you get a message that curl is *being held back* you probably need to re-install/manually upgrade it

Comment: if you are using package installer from cli then you can try `sudo apt-get install -f` to install dependencies?

Comment: take it to superuser.com or serverfault.com , SO isn't for debugging your package manager issues, unless you're actually developing one.

Comment: @Girish wouldn't do that, it would force install incompatible versions of php libs, would probably break his php installation

Comment: If you have *upgraded* Debian 9 (stretch) to 10 (buster) and you're using packages.sury.org, make sure you've also updated *that* repository to Debian 10, i.e. `deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ buster main`